# Clone and chain issue in laravel query builder and queues

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-queue

Please consider my class constructor :

```
public function __construct(User $query = null)
{
    $this->query = $query ?: (new User())->getQuery();
}
```

I have a method like this :

```
public function getNullActivityUsers()
{
    $query = clone $this->query;

    $query->whereNull('activity');

    return $query->get();
}
```

When I call this method, the sql query will be this :

```
select * from `users` where `activity` is null
```

But when I push this method into **laravel queue**, the query will be this :

```
select * from `users`
```

In fact, the chaining method of `whereNull` would not be called in that method. I should change the method to this version:

```
public function getNullActivityUsers()
{
    $query = clone $this->query;

    $query = $query->whereNull('activity');

    return $query->get();
}
```

This will do the trick : **$query =** $query->whereNull('activity');

But I want to know, why laravel acts differently in this case. Because if I test the method outside the queue, the chaining will be there. But if I run it throw queue, it will get other result.

(( Imagine that I should use that `clone` always. ))

Comment: Try to chain and return in the same time : `return  $query->whereNull('activity')->get();` !!

Comment: I know!! But imagine that I want to do that in this way. In fact, I want to know about the different results of laravel.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it and if it's working like this I would say it's a bug.

However the most important thing is - have you stopped / restarted queue before verifying what is going one? You might get false-positive in such case because queue will use the old code. Each time you make changes in your code you should restart queue worker to make sure it will see the changes made in your code. See [Queue workers and deployment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#queue-workers-and-deployment) section if this is the case.

Comment: @MisaGH Can you show how exactly you push "this method" into queue?

Comment: With this, I push a process method and in this method I called the above method. `Queue::push(static::class . '@process', [], 'normal');`

Comment: It just create new user object and call that method and then I used dd to view the query and it is described in question.
`$user = new UserManager();` `$user->getNullActivityUsers()` UserManage is my main class that I started question with its constructor